# Alternative to Inkscape that does not embed software-specific tags in the SVG

Tags: linux, image-editor, vector-graphics, svg

[Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/) has a number of useful features, but it tends to create SVGs with certain Inkscape-specific tags which makes it difficult for SVG editing software on other platforms (such as [Adobe Illustrator](http://www.adobe.com/products/illustrator.html)) to open them.

Is there an alternative SVG editor for Linux (Ubuntu) that does not have this problem?

Comment: While it's fine to ask for alternatives, the name of the app to replace shouldn't be the only explanation to what you're looking for. Please list your requirements explicitly. See [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 4):

The only alternative I know of to InkScape is [sK1](http://sk1project.org/):

[image: Source: Wikipedia]
Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:SK1.png)

I've only used it for simple web design SVG editing, but it appeared to work fine. Less features than InkScape, but it does seem to import from proprietry programmes (such as CorelDRAW) a little better than InkScape. It exports to PostScript, and thus to Adobe Illustrator (5.0) rather well.

It's certainly in the Fedora repos:

```
sudo yum install sK1
```

(Note: the capital `K` when installing, but `sk1` to launch from the command-line)

It may not be in the Ubuntu repos any more, but webup8 have made a PPA, have a look [HERE](http://www.webupd8.org/2009/09/sk1-ubuntu-repository-vector-graphics.html)

Answer (score 4):

Inkscape allows to edit and export standard SVG, without Inkscape metadata.

Try to Save as > Plain SVG.